# NetBeans atajos de teclado

Tags: netbeans

Buenas quisiera saber si hay algún lugar donde pueda encontrar todos los atajos que tiene el NetBeans. también quisiera saber si son editables o se pueden agregar nuevos.
Busco uno en particular: seleccionar en bloque pero NO el Toggle Rectangular Seleccion, porque si quiero escribir con esa selección, en las líneas que están vacías también me las rellena.
En VSCode usaba uno con las teclas (Shift+ Alt+ seleccionar con el mouse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A julio de 2021, [este enlace](https://www.jrebel.com/blog/netbeans-shortcuts) parece funcionar bien.

En el fondo, la idea es que tú mismo puedes configurar los atajos de teclado en *Preferencias* como mejor se acomoden a tu forma de trabajar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]